# browserify/vueify: inject global scss file in all components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, browserify, vueify

In an app I am using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify). I am trying to inject global scss file (with variables, mixins, colors etc..) into Vue to make it available for all components (instead to have the file explicitly imported in each components).

I have the following main.scss at path public/app/styles/main.scss:

```
// public/app/styles/main.scss

// Helpers
@import "helpers/mixins";
@import "helpers/variables";
@import "helpers/colors";


// Base
@import "base/reset";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/base";


// Layout
@import "base/layout";
```

In the gulp.js file I have the following:

```
// gulp.js

gulp.task("build_js", () => {

    return browserify({
        entries: config.app.index,
        cache: {},
        dev: true
    })
        // [...]
        .transform(vueify, {
            sass: {
                includePaths: ["public/app/styles", "public/app/styles/main.scss"]
            }
        })
        // [...]

});
```

This is the App.vue component where I've tried to use a global defined scss variable:

```
<!--App.vue-->

<template>

    <div id="app"></div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        name: "App"

    }

</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

    #app {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: $backgroundColor;        
    }

</style>
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$backgroundColor". while parsing file: D:\Users\revy\Documents\myapp\public\app\components\App.vue
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your variable `$backgroundColor` has not been defined. Most likely, the file that defines it has not been bundled.

You can solve that by importing your `main.scss` file in the component style block, and it should be resolved.

```
<!--App.vue-->

<template>

    <div id="app"></div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        name: "App"

    }

</script>

<style lang="scss" src="public/app/styles/main.scss"></style>
<style scoped lang="scss">

    @import "public/app/style/main.scss";

    #app {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: $backgroundColor;        
    }

</style>
```

You might have to change the path, as I am not sure what your files structire looks like.

However if the import doesn't work, You can try including the file directly from the component using a `style` tag with a `src` attribute :

```
<!--App.vue-->

<template>

    <div id="app"></div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        name: "App"

    }

</script>

<style lang="scss" src="public/app/styles/main.scss"></style>
<style scoped lang="scss">

    #app {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: $backgroundColor;        
    }

</style>
```

With this syntax, the bundler will load the SCSS file directly and resolve all the imports within.

Comment: yes I know that with the @import syntax works, but I would like to know why is not working using the vueify option includePaths. I've also tried with wildcards like "public/app/styles/**/*.scss" but same result